# Set variable equal to class color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my css file I have:

```
.activeStar {
    @include themify($themes) {
        color: themed('activeStar');
    }
}
```

I need to set a variable in my .js file in React equal to whatever color the above css pulls since it will change based on the set theme.

```
var activeStar = '???';
```

I am using the ReactStars component which requires the color be defined when the plugin is called and does not assign classes but need this color to change based on the theme.